# Get ListItemID using ExecuteQueryAsync function

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model

In the code below I can get the value of the ListItemID of a List.

```
var siteUrl = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/demo';
var t;
 retrieveListItemsInclude();
 alert("after"+t);
function retrieveListItemsInclude() {
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
   var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('My tasks');
   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
   camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID" Ascending ="FALSE"><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><OrderBy></View>');
   this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
   clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Id)');
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
 alert('inside'+t);
}
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
   var listItemInfo = '';
   var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

   while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
       var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
       listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id();
   }
t=listItemInfo;

}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
   alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}
```

I need to set the value of the listItemID to a global variable e.g.t.

The variable **listItemInfo** is declared inside the inside onQuerySucceeded function.
The scope of the **listItemInfo** is limited to the **onQuerySucceeded function**.

I need to pass it to the gobal variable.

1)Can I set the return value in OnSuccesded funcation and set it to another value.

If I add an alert inside the `onQuerySucceeded()` function . I get the value of the function.

I have set the value of the global variable t=listItemInfo.

When I alert the value of t inside the parent `retrieveListItemsInclude()` function. I get an undefined value.

I understand that the `ExecuteQueryAync()` function is an asynchronous function but I am facing the following issues

1) I get an undefined value after the `retrieveListItemsInclude();` is called

2) If I change the call the ExecuteQueryAsync function to

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
```

3) The above code change did not make any difference but worked strangely. When I paste the code in firebug . The first time I get an undefined value but the next the value of the ID. Could this be due to caching.

What is the best way to return a value from the QuerySucceded function.

4) In IE when I edit the page the code works but when I stop editing the page it does not work. Do I need to provide the path for the SP.JS file explicitly or am I missing something

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript Client Object Model. The code execution does not wait for the `onQuerySucceeded()` to complete. Hence  `alert("after"+t);` is immediately called and at this point it correctly shows `undefined`. However, if the same code is written afterwards at some arbitrary position in the file (And by that time assuming that `onQuerySucceeded()` will have completed), then it will correctly show the output. Now in order to make sure that `alert("after"+t);` is not executed until `onQuerySucceeded()` is completed, this can be done using:

1. Using JavaScript Callbacks
2. Using JQuery Deferreds/Promises

Example using Callbacks:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //don't exectute any jsom until sp.js file has loaded.        
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', prepareTables);
    });

function prepareTables() {
    getItemsWithCaml('External User Account Request',
            function (camlItems) {
                var listItemEnumerator = camlItems.getEnumerator();
                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var listItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                    console.log(listItem.get_item('Title'));
                } console.log('Completed table prparation.');
            },
            function (sender, args) {
                console.log('An error occured while retrieving list items:' + args.get_message());
            });
}    

function getItemsWithCaml(listTitle, success, error) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var camlItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(camlItems);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                success(camlItems);
            },
            error
        );
};
```

Example using Deferreds/Promises

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //don't exectute any jsom until sp.js file has loaded.        
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', prepareTables);
    });    

function prepareTables() {
    getItemsWithCaml('External User Account Request').then(
            function (camlItems) {
                var listItemEnumerator = camlItems.getEnumerator();
                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var listItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                    console.log(listItem.get_item('Title'));
                } console.log('Completed table prparation.');
            },
            function (sender, args) {
                console.log('An error occured while retrieving list items:' + args.get_message());
            }
        );   
}    

function getItemsWithCaml(listTitle) {
    //use of $.Deferred in the executeQueryAsync delegate allows the consumer of this method to write 'syncronous like' code
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();        
    var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(items);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this,
            function () { deferred.resolve(items); }),
        Function.createDelegate(this,
            function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args); }));

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

See this for more information:
http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/10/sharepoint-using-deferredspromises-or.html